# Connecting MySQL to Scala using slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am trying to connect MySQL database do scala application using slick 3.1
In demo which is provided by Typesafe, this code is used as application.conf :

```
h2mem1 = {
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
  driver = org.h2.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

I am running MySQL database on ampps apache server and now I am confused regarding what to enter as url and driver so that my application can connect to database?
Should my url be "localhost"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
database = {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"  
  user = "user"
  password = "pwd"
  driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```